# Grouping tests in Rust/Cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I really love `cargo` and how easy it is to write unit tests.

However, it seems like it's testing functionality is fairly basic. What I'd like to be able to do is have named groups of tests somehow. What I am trying to accomplish is to have a default set of tests that execute when you run the basic `cargo test`. However, some of my tests take much longer to run, so I'd like to be able to move these to another group of extended tests that I can run with some command like `cargo test --extended`, and also the ability to be able to run *all* the tests at once easily. I also have a third group of tests that I have currently implemented as `ignored` tests so I can run them separately.

Even though all my tests are effectively unit tests, I tried to accomplish this by creating a `tests` directory as you would do with integration tests. However it seems that the basic `cargo test` command wants to run the *all* these tests, i.e. the normal tests that are part of my crate as well as the extended tests in the `tests` crate.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this or whether there is some crate that provides this functionality?

Comment: This grouping and chosen execution is described in the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html

Comment: This section of the book just discusses unit tests and integrations test, which don't fully cover my use case. Integrations tests would be alright except that they are all run when running `cargo test`. My solution was to use cargo features to optionally compile in the expensive tests as described in the reddit post linked by moy2010 in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of `feature` flags and the `#ignore` macro as mentioned here: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3i1nki/how_to_skip_expensive_tests_with_cargo_test/